# Is there a public status for https://repo.magento.com/

Tags: magento2, ssl, composer

Is there a status for https://repo.magento.com/  to check if everything is working fine and decide if it is a local issue or not?

It seems that this morning the repo is not responding and information is loaded from cache with no 2.1:

```
The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
https://repo.magento.com could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.0.4, 0.42.0-beta7, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.1.0-rc1] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`composer diagnose` is a better option.

Foound out what the issue was:

```
The OpenSSL library (0.9.8y) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.
```

Answer (score 2):

For those landing here looking for the Magento Composer Repo up-time status, it is located here - https://status.adobe.com/products/3350

Click on "Experience Cloud" in the menu and then on "Magento Composer Repo" in the sub menu.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any offical page.

Not great but I guess you can check access to: https://repo.magento.com/packages.json

http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/repo.magento.com.html